# wp_mail only sends emails to gmail

Tags: wp-mail

wp_mail only sends emails to gmail and i receive emails only on gmail inbox but in dedicated servers couldnt send recieve anything even as spam
followed data works well only to gmail

```
        add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', array( $this, 'set_html_mail_content_type' ) );
       
        $to = myacc@gmail.com;

        $subject = 'test';
        
        wp_mail( $to, $subject, 'body');

        remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', array( $this, 'set_html_mail_content_type' ) );
```

Comment: How have you configured WordPress to send emails? Are you using the default, which is a local SMTP server running on your WordPress server I think? How is that set up to route onward email? Is the from address you're using on a domain that's set up for SPF i.e. it is likely to be flagged as spam if it's sent from the wrong servers?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to WPD stack exchange.

as I am see its look like  sometimes we have forgot to add some basic need and function not working properly.

Please try with header parameter:

```
$headers[] = 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8';  
$headers[] = 'From:' . "testing@gmail.com";
```

Also, you can use  [Easy WP SMTP](https://wp-ecommerce.net/easy-wordpress-smtp-send-emails-from-your-wordpress-site-using-a-smtp-server-2197) and enable debugging and/or set that up to use SMTP.  If something like GMail works then you'll know it is a server setting and not this code.